# SCSS for a top bar

Tags: html, css, sass

I want to put a background gradient topbar behind a link but I'm not able to figure out the styling. There is empty space around the topbar although the padding is 0px and the link is not coming out as white.

This should be very simple but apparently not so for a styling newbie like me 
:-(
Thanks!

```
<main class="col-md-9 float-left col px-5 pl-md-2 pt-2 main">
    <div class="topbar">
        <a href="#" data-target="#sidebar" data-toggle="collapse">
            <i class="fa fa-navicon fa-2x py-2 p-1"></i>
        </a>
    </div>
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</main>

.topbar {
  background: linear-gradient(#004812, #0B7225, #3A9250);
  padding : 0px;
  &::a {
    color:white
  }
}
```

Comment: can you provide an example in fiddler or plnkr?

Comment: Created plunker http://plnkr.co/edit/skIsC23kzsU5EvXUkrw9 although no styling is working there. Locally at least I have the styling with couple of issues as mentioned in the question originally. Thanks for responding! @Naresh217

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because of the styles already set. I am a newbie so I had had to figure that by setting the padding in 'pl-md-0 pt-0` the padding can be removed.

```
<main class="col-md-9 float-left col px-5 pl-md-2 pt-2 main">
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to give height to the topbar and most important thing may be your scss file is not compile properly. Try out this code.

```
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>
<body>
<main class="col-md-9 float-left col px-5 pl-md-2 pt-2 main">
    <div class="topbar">
        <a href="#" data-target="#sidebar" data-toggle="collapse">
            <i class="fa fa-navicon fa-2x py-2 p-1"></i>Testing
        </a>
    </div>
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</main>
</body>
</html>
```

Scss code

```
.topbar {
    width:100%;
    height:50px;
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#004812, #0B7225, #3A9250);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(#004812, #0B7225, #3A9250);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(#004812, #0B7225, #3A9250);
    background: linear-gradient(#004812, #0B7225, #3A9250);
    padding : 10px 0;
    position:relative;
    a {
        color: #fff;   
      }
    }
```

You can check it codepen link is given below.[https://codepen.io/varshaCodepen/pen/QOaEyK]

Answer (score 0):

your code is working correctly. I can't find any problem. If your styles doesn't work, try to check other styles that you have and set to parent or divs

```
.topbar {
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#004812, #0B7225, #3A9250);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(#004812, #0B7225, #3A9250);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(#004812, #0B7225, #3A9250);
    background: linear-gradient(#004812, #0B7225, #3A9250);
    padding : 0px;
    a {
        color:white
      }
    }
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/aminqp/cwvf709y/)